# OnItemLongClickListener does not work on Firebase Database populated ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a listView populated from a FirebaseDatabase and I want to delete the items using onIntemLongClickListener, but it doesn't work at all, the event is never called. What do I need to add to the code in order to make it work? Thanks! PS: I don't have any errors in the logs related to this. I also tried to open a new activity, but it does not work neither.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        car = new Car();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view_main);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.list_title, list);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + position );
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddCarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Database Call

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        car = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Car.class);
                        if (!list.contains(car.getLicenceNumber()))
                            list.add(car.getLicenceNumber());
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
    }
```

CardView

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_main"
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="367dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:longClickable="true"/>
```

Comment: At the `OnItemLongClickListener` your code it is saying that you are going to another `Activity` to the `AddCarActivity.class` you are not trying to delete something.

Comment: I know, It was just to test it, but it doesn't work anyway. It did not open a new activity

Comment: try to show a Log when you listen for click if it shows or not ?

Comment: I tried, but nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `android:longClickable="true"` from your ListView as this might be consuming the long click event.

Comment: Remove android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" from LinearLayout also.

Comment: I am able to see the data in the list view, however I can do nothing with the list items. I changed the initialization of the adapter, thanks.

Comment: Try to remove android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" from LinearLayout also & check if it's working or not.